# How to remove execute from a folder with subfolders

Tags: permissions, executable

I have a bunch of *.mp3 in a folder with several subfolders.
They are currently  -rwxrwxrwx 1
I would like these .mp3's to be changed to:  -rw-rw-r-- 1
There is nothing in these folders that need to be executable.
How might I do this from command line?

Comment: See [how can I recursively run chmod -x?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327562/how-can-i-recursively-run-chmod-x)

Comment: @matigo won't that stomp on the subfolders' `x` bits as well?

Comment: Yeah, based on the answer linked by @steeldriver : `find /path/to/folder -name "*.mp3" -exec chmod 664 {} +`

Comment: Don't ever run chmod -R 664 because it will break all your directories.

Comment: @matigo directories need x permission, otherwise they don't work (one can't enter them). The `-R` flag to `chmod` is generally of no use because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `find somefolder -type f -exec chmod o-w,gou-x {} +`

Relative permissions are much safer, and you don't want to stomp on directory x permission.